# Get post data in AuthorizeAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, authorize-attribute

**Hi,**

I am about to validate some data before letting the user in to the action and if the data do not validate, then I need to redirect to another action.

The question is how I get the post data that is sent to the action from within the AuthorizeAttribute?

Comment: Just so I understand... you want to receive a POST request with an action on your controller, ensure that the model (hydrated from your HTTP POST Request Forms collection) is valid.  If the model is not valid, then redirect the user to another action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for, but this will give you access to the request data from within your `MyAuthorizeAttribute`.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = true, Inherited = true)]
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext;
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        // do stuff with request
    }
}
```

You can then get any data that was sent in the request.

Comment: Okay I found it under httpContext.Request.Form but I will not get the values as a viewObject, instead I will have to look in a dictionary to get the data that later on is parsed into the view class?

Comment: Yes, you can get form values from `httpContext.Request.Form` (as a `NameValueCollection`) or you can get values from the QueryString using `httpContext.Request.QueryString` (also as a `NameValueCollection`)

Comment: Okay so there is no way of getting the data parsed into the view object?